# My bundle.js file is much smaller after deploying to Netlify. What sorcery is this?

Tags: node.js, browserify, netlify

I deployed a little web app to Netlify and noticed my bundle.js file is only 157kb. When I run a production build locally, it's 575kb. I'm not mad about it, but how is Netlify doing that?

The app is using browserify to bundle my scripts as well as babel and uglify. `browserify script.js | uglifyjs > dist/bundle.js` That's the same script I told Netlify to run in the settings.

I think it must be some kind of default setting on Netlify builds?

I thought it might be my NODE_ENV environment variable was set to development, but I double checked and it's set to production. I even tried adding `set NODE_ENV=production &&` before my build script just to make sure.

Is Netlify magic? What else could be different between my local setup and Netlify?

Comment: How are you measuring the sizes? Is it possibly a browser reporting the gzip size compared to Explorer/Finder reporting the file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `gzip`?

Read more about it here: https://www.gzip.org/

See if there's a header called `Content-Encoding: gzip` and you'll know for sure.

Comment: Hmm, maybe... Is there a good way to check?

The filename is still just bundle.js, not bundle.gz. I took a look at the bundle.js on Netlify and it's the exact same length as my local bundle.js. -- despite being 400kb smaller?!

Comment: Did you try seeing header `Content-Encoding`?

Comment: Yep!  `content-encoding: gzip` in the netlify response header.  `content-encoding: application/javascript` on the local one.

Netlfiy, you sneaky g-zippin son of a gun. Thank you!

Comment: If there's Nginx, there's probably `gzip`: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/